# deploy Vuejs app in folder of an amazon bucket?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-s3

I want to deploy a vuejs app in a folder of an Amazon bucket.
I succeeded in another app by setting publicpath to "./" in vue.config.js but in this app it does not work and maybe it is because in this app I use vue router to display the correct page.

Does anyones have any procedure in order to accomplish that please?

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in your S3 bucket for [Website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EnableWebsiteHosting.html). Create dist folder of your Vue app and then copy it to your S3 bucket. Enable web hosting from S3 and expose your site using Cloudfront or/and API gateway. We are doing similar thing with Angular and Vue apps and it is working great in prod. [Here is one more resource.](https://blogs.halodoc.io/deploy-static-web-application-using-s3-and-cloudfront/). Its very simple to setup and you can use CICD pipeline stage to push new code in S3 bucket using CLI. Minimal downtime with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean AWS S3 Buckets you have to export your site to a static website.

If you want to stick with Vue, you could use this plugin: https://github.com/multiplegeorges/vue-cli-plugin-s3-deploy but I personally would recommend you to use nuxt which enables you to simply export your vue pages as a static website (see here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/static-site-generation)